# how to get my label id in jquery if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this for loop that generates labels for each data entry in the array? what i need to do now is write an if statement to check if a certain label is clicked because only that one id has more data in it to display in the next page, for the rest of the buttons i only want an alert to pop up saying there is no data available! following is the picture of the results and actual code!

PIC:
[image]

i only want purchase sundry's label's id to go to next page the rest should throw alert!

here is code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://41.134.206.60/wf7_api/api/inbox/johnny", function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var high = data[i].High;
        var medium = data[i].Medium;
        var low = data[i].Low;
        var sum = high + medium + low;
        $("#showdata").html("tasks");
        $("#shownames").append("<label id="+ data[i].ProcessID +" onclick="+"redirectme();"+" style="+"text-align:center;"+"font-size:x-large;"+">"+ data[i].ProcessName +"</label><label style="+"font-size:x-large;"+">("+sum+")</label><labels class="+"lowpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+low+"</labels><labels class="+"mediumpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+medium+"</labels><labels class="+"highpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+high+"</labels></br>");
        };
    } , 'json');
});​

function redirectme(){
var r = document.getElementById("76");

window.location.href = "Datapage.html";
}
```

what currently is happening is every label is going to Datapage.hmtl, i only want the one label with a specific id to go to the datapage.html, the rest should throw an alert? how do i get this done? i am new to this!

using cordova/html5/javascript/jquery/visual studio 2010

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some of the html of the table, that would be helpful. You need to use the specific id of the label to check if it was clicked. Also `#showdata` and `#shownames` are defined as id's (while their names imply there are several of them), plese make sure an id is unique.

Comment: <label id="+ data[i].ProcessID +"   makes the label id unique! there is no html to show because this is all dynamic, only the div's with id's #showdata and shownames is on the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole section of code needs a rewrite but if you just need it to work then this is what you need to change:

```
$("#shownames").append("<label id="+ data[i].ProcessID +" onclick="+"redirectme(" + data[i].ProcessID + ");"+" style="+"text-align:center;"+"font-size:x-large;"+">"+ data[i].ProcessName +"</label><label style="+"font-size:x-large;"+">("+sum+")</label><labels class="+"lowpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+low+"</labels><labels class="+"mediumpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+medium+"</labels><labels class="+"highpic"+" id="+"righty"+">"+high+"</labels></br>");
```

And the handling function:

```
function redirectme(processId){
    if(processId == 76)
    {
        window.location.href = "Datapage.html";
    } else {
        // write your logic to show the popup or w/e.
    }
}
```

I'm happy to do a fiddle for you in a way that would be much easier to maintain and change if you're interested just drop a comment below.

Comment: whoop whoop! thanks alot this worked just like i wanted it to! this is just a test run to show company that a few things is possible in mobile development!, but yes please i would like to see how other poeple might do it? i wanna learn more :P

Comment: @Arrie Have a look at the method I used here: http://jsfiddle.net/eWNKx/3/ You will see that whenever you need to change something, you just update the template and dont have to go digging through tons of strings to attach handlers etc. Hope this helps!